# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch data from rest api using axios
and i want to store data in an array and append new property children
but i am getting error
here is my code:

```
var categoriesTree = {};
axios.get('https://akkar.market/wp-json/wp/v2/job_listing_category?per_page=100')
.then(response => {
  categoriesTree = response.data
  categoriesTree.forEach(category => {
    if (category.parent === 0) {
      if (!(category.id in categoriesTree)) {
        categoriesTree[category.id] = {'name': category.name, 'children': []};
      } else {
        categoriesTree[category.id]['name'] = category.name;
      }
    } else {
      if (!category.parent in categoriesTree) {
        categoriesTree['parent'] = {'name': '', 'children': []};
      }
      categoriesTree['parent']['children'].push({'name': category.name, 'id': category.id});
    }
  })
})
console.log(categoriesTree)
```

i am getting this error:
[image]

Comment: try logging `categoriesTree['parent']` and see what it has

Comment: My guess is that `categoriesTree.parent` is not worth 0 but is not worth an `Array` aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are a couple of problems:

1. In `!category.parent in categoriesTree`, you'd taking the logical NOT of `category.parent` (which will be `true` or `false`) and using that result in the `in` operation. You need `()` around the `in` expression: `!(category.parent in categoriesTree)`
2. Even with the revision, that checks for a property whose name is the value of `category.parent` in `categoriesTree`. But then you create a property called `parent`, not a property with the name from `category.parent`.

If the property is supposed to be the value of `category.parent`, use that instead of `'parent'`:

```
if (!(category.parent in categoriesTree)) {
    categoriesTree[category.parent] = {'name': '', 'children': []};
}
categoriesTree[category.parent]['children'].push({'name': category.name, 'id': category.id});
```

If it's supposed to be called `parent` (literally), then use that consistently instead:

```
if (!("parent" in categoriesTree)) {
    categoriesTree.parent = {'name': '', 'children': []};
}
categoriesTree.parent['children'].push({'name': category.name, 'id': category.id});
```

---

If `categoriesTree` will either not have a property called `x` or the property will have an object reference as a value, you can use `if (!categoriesTree.x`)`rather than`if (!("x" in categoriesTree))`. Applying that to the two options above:

```
if (!categoriesTree[category.parent])) {
    categoriesTree[category.parent] = {'name': '', 'children': []};
}
categoriesTree[category.parent]['children'].push({'name': category.name, 'id': category.id});
```

If it's supposed to be called `parent` (literally), then use that consistently instead:

```
if (!categoriesTree.parent)) {
    categoriesTree.parent = {'name': '', 'children': []};
}
categoriesTree.parent['children'].push({'name': category.name, 'id': category.id});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you mean under `if (!category.parent in categoriesTree)`, but it looks like it always will return `false`. Try to change this condition simply to `if (!categoriesTree.parent)`, and I suppose it will work.

Comment: i try but it still give me error on this line  categoriesTree['parent']['children'].push({'name': category.name, 'id': category.id});

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my answer, not `if (!category.parent)` but `if (!categoriesTree.parent)` :)